# Sharepoint Requirements for SOAP/REST API

Tags: php, sharepoint, rest, soap, sharepoint-2010

I am not anywhere near familiar with MS Sharepoint, however I am in charge of a project to do some light integration into an existing Sharepoint server. As I am aware, the version of Sharepoint is the newest, and is running in a sandbox environment.

The main thing I have to accomplish here is to create new users via PHP calls (whether RESTful or SOAP web services). I know there are APIs into Sharepoint, but they do not seem very well documented on something that would seem so simple.

Also, I have gotten messages from colleagues saying that Sharepoint **relies** on Active Directory for user management which would seem hard to believe. In that case I would have to create an LDAP connection as well I suppose.

The main question here is, does anyone know what steps I would need to do in order to create a new user via a REST or SOAP call to a server running **just** Sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 supports three authentication modes: Windows, Forms Based, or Claims Based.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx

What you need to do is add the users to the appropriate authentication store, and them add the to security groups withing SharePoint to give them rights.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcpermissions.aspx

Comment: So this being said, a MySQL server would be a suitable Forms-Based authentication?

Comment: Also, sorry to double post, but I just read there is an LDAP component that is installed with Sharepoint, can I use this to add users to via PHP and grant permissions after creation?

Comment: re MySQL and FBA: Yes, but you'd have to find or write a provider for MySQL. The .NET Framework does not include one.

Comment: re LDAP: Yes, exactly. I don't know how to add a user to LDAP via PHP code but I would assume it's possible. Then you could give the user permissions in SharePoint using the Permissions web service.